# How do I add a custom emoji to a nickname with Discord.js?

Tags: discord, discord.js

I'm trying to add a custom emoji to a user's nickname with Discord.js. I have tried everything from `:emojiname:` to `:emojiname:emojiID`, with no luck.

For example:
`guildMember.setNickname('<:myemoji:> Name');`

or

`guildMember.setNickname('<:myemoji:myemojiID> Name');`

Am I missing something, or is this not currently possible?

Answer (score 0):

As of April 6, 2022, this is not possible, confirmed via the official Discord.js Discord server.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).